# connect to TDengine via restful, but the port is not monitored

Tags: rest, tdengine

When I try to connect TDengine via its restful API but its 6041 port is not monitored.

Following is more detail info.

systemctl status taosd

```
● taosd.service - TDengine server service
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/taosd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (running) since Wed 2021-10-20 15:08:33 CST; 48min ago
Process: 16246 ExecStartPre=/usr/local/taos/bin/startPre.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 16257 (taosd)
Tasks: 57
Memory: 30.1M
CGroup: /system.slice/taosd.service
└─16257 /usr/bin/taosd

Oct 20 15:08:33 ecs-29b3 systemd[1]: Starting TDengine server service...
Oct 20 15:08:33 ecs-29b3 systemd[1]: Started TDengine server service.
Oct 20 15:08:33 ecs-29b3 TDengine:[16257]: Starting TDengine service...
Oct 20 15:08:33 ecs-29b3 TDengine:[16257]: Started TDengine service successfully.
```

netstat -antp|grep 6030

```
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:6030 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 16257/taosd
netstat -antp|grep 6041
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check whether taosadapter is running with `ps -e | grep taosadapter`, If there is no taosadapter running, you should start it.

Comment: Yes. you are definitely right.